# Hosting Web Service in IIS - Not able to access the service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Service Application project in Visual Studio that contains the following files

- ZooWebService.svc
- WebConfig

I attempted to host the Web Service in IIS but when i browse to my web service from IIS the Web Service does not load at all. It just says "loading" in the browser.

Here is my WebConfig file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
    <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
     </appSettings>
     <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
     </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" 
     name="WCFWebService.ZooWCFService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
     contract="WCFWebService.IZooWCFService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
        contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        </service>
      </services>
       <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
         </serviceBehaviors>
       </behaviors>
     </system.serviceModel>
     </configuration>
```

I did the following so what have i done wrong?

1. Open IIS
2. Right clicked on Default Website
3. Selected "Add Application"
4. Populated "Alias" field
5. Populated "Physical Path" to directory of where the solution contents are
6. Clicked OK
7. Rebuilt the solution in Visual Studio

Comment: In IIS what is your authentication set to? Do you have a binding in IIS set for port 8080, and in your project under properties -> Web is it pointing to http://localhost:8080?

Comment: I will check this. The IIS i am using is IIS 10 on my local machine running Windows 10. Does this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don’t need to specify the base address in the configuration file which needs to be set up in the web site binding module.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d42fc165-052d-476a-9580-1240b3d0293d/specify-endpoint-in-wcf-webconfig?forum=wcf
then we should enable the WCF feature in the IIS.
[image]
At last we could see the web service description in http://ip:port/xxxx.svc.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: I don't see WCF Services option in "Turn Windows features on and off". I'm trying to host the service in IIS 10 locally that is running on Windows 10.

Secondly, as stated in the link you shared. If i want to use specific port do i need to set this in IIS or leave it unassigned and remove the base address from the config file?

Comment: Yes, you could leave it unassigned and remove the base address from the config file.
“Turn windows feature on and off” located in the control panel, Programs and features, left menu bar when our OS is window 10. wish you good luck.

Comment: Great it's working now, i removed baseAddresses element. I also activated HTTP Activation module under .NET Framework 3.5.
I also activated WCF Services under .NET Framework 4.7 Advanced Services. I ticked HTTP Activation as your screenshot demonstrated.

Thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 1):

For enabling the WCF in IIS, you may have to enable the HTTP activation feature for the .net framework first.

Some of links to do this
https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-326D6F7B-08EC-43EB-A5A7-9C51DD9E555C

https://pubs.vmware.com/mirage-56/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.mirage.api.pg.doc%2FGUID-552D845B-E530-4898-A06B-4F73E668BEFF.html

Once this is done you may try to deploy WCF directly from the visual studio to your local IIS>

Right click on the WCFproject -> go to properties -> in properties window -> select web tab  -> in servers section select Local IIS and click on Create Virtual Directory.

Now run the WCF from Visual studio, this will host the WCF in local IIS.

[image: sample]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I think it will help others who are experiencing the same issue as i did. I managed to resolve the issue by using your links as well as the above Abraham Qian's post.