# WCF Web Service : How to run?

Tags: wcf

Am planning to build a WCF Web service using Visual Studio 2015. I came up with a sample web service that i can launch from visual studio and this works fine when i call the APIs from browser on local host.

Now i want to deploy it in a server. Am not sure how I can deploy in a server. The final out put of the web service is a DLL.

Can someone explain to me how to deploy this in a Windows server?

Do i need to run this web service DLL as a service?

Does it got anything to do with IIS?

Comment: WCF Services can either be [hosted in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-iis), or as a [windows service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-a-managed-windows-service)

Comment: @ColinM - Can i host the DLL in a IIS or Windows Service? How will it get exposed to outside world via netowrk?

Comment: If you want it exposed then host via IIS, see the link in my previous message

Comment: @ColinM - You can add that as answer and I'll accept it. Yes, I need it exposed to outside world.

Comment: when you encounter the problem during the process of publishing the project to IIS, please refer to the following link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029543/hosting-web-service-in-iis-not-able-to-access-the-service/54032310#54032310

Comment: If, not when, but otherwise a good point to raise, Abraham.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your request, I have made this an answer.

If you're looking to host a WCF service which is exposed to the outside world then the best solution is to host the service via IIS which you can find out how to do by reviewing the [following article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-iis).

You can find a more visual tutorial [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/hosting-wcf-service-on-iis/).

If you encounter errors after publishing to IIS then please refer to the following [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54032310/5062791) to see which Windows Features must be enabled.